# How to stop printing stack trace of error in nginx + angularJS + springboot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, nginx, nginx-config, spring-restcontroller

As you know, we should not print error details especially stack trace of the error to frontend, no matter if it was caused by a bad request or a backend service internal error.

It is not only for good user experience but also for avoiding hacker analyzing and finding something useful for the following attack.

Our service is
frontend: nginx + angularJS
backend: spring-boot

We have backend exception returns and angularJS has handled all exception returns.
But when the attacker tried to use burpsuite, a software to attack, after changing the host value in the HTTP field, it return HTTP error 400, "Host does not match SNI", and printed stack trace...

[image]

My question is, how to stop printing such errors, especially the stack trace?
And one minor ask is why it print something related to Jetty.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks

Comment: YOu are either using Jetty as an embedded server or deploying to an embedded server. Assuming it is the embedded one you should be able to add `server.error.include-stacktrace` and set it to `never` and `server.error.include-exception` to `false` (although that should be the defaults). If you are deploying to Jetty you will need to explicitly configure Jetty for this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice, I will try to add above configure and retry. Just one more double confirm, is that for backend(Jetty) not returning stacktrace/exception to frontend? or just stop print stacktrace/exception at backend log file?

Comment: Well you probably want it in the backend for investigative purposes.

Comment: hmm, if server.error.include-stacktrace and server.error.include-exception are for backend error log , then it not help on my issue, my issue is when user change host name and make 400 error, how to avoid present error details including stack trace, which is considered unsafe